# What is the relation between Lightning Record Page and Page Layout?

Tags: lightning, lightning-record-page

Does lightning record page overrides the standard page layout in salesforce? Updates on the standard page layout seems to not taking effect if lightning record page is active. How are fields' FLS configured on Lightning record page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Page Layouts govern the Record Detail component on the Lightning Record Page, if present. They also govern the presentation of Related Lists and which fields and buttons are shown there.

Additionally, Page Layouts and Compact Layouts govern the fields present in the highlights panel (if present) and the Quick Actions available as buttons or as publisher.

So neither really overrides the other: Page Layouts and Lightning Record Pages work together. However, if the Lightning Record Page does not show a Record Detail component, much of what you'd expect from the Page Layout won't be visible. If you don't see changes you expect, it's possible you do not have the correct Page Layout assigned to the current user profile and record type.

FLS is not configured on Lightning Record Pages or on Page Layouts. Page Layouts may mark a field read only, but this applies only to interaction with that specific layout. FLS is configured in Profiles and Permission Sets.

Comment: There is also the page session caching issue - this is frequently seen on scratch orgs where changes in the layout don't take effect until the page structure cache expires. You can turn this off in the Session Settings in Setup.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Lightning Record Pages can override the standard page layout in Salesforce. When you create a Lightning Record Page for a specific object, it takes precedence over the standard page layout for users accessing Salesforce through the Lightning Experience or the Salesforce mobile app.

Updates to the standard page layout may not reflect on the Lightning Record Page immediately. This is because Lightning Record Pages have their own configurations, including components, tabs, and layouts. If you want to make changes to the page layout for Lightning Record Pages, you'll need to modify the Lightning Record Page directly.

There is a lot of development going on around the feature of 'Lightning Record Pages' and I am under the impression that Salesforce will eventually switch fully to LRP and retire page layouts.

Please find the below article which is a very good one.

https://www.salesforceben.com/salesforce-page-layouts-vs-lightning-record-pages/